Is it recommended to use a npm package with missing files?
I am using faceapi.js in a react project. While importing, the console gives some warnings and error of files missing from the node modules folder.
As I am a beginner I am not sure about using the same in my react project and can use it for production or not!
Errors
WARNING in ./node_modules/face-api.js/build/es6/xception/TinyXception.js

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):

Failed to parse source map from 'D:\\D\\Git\\Temp\\face-api\\node_modules\\face-api.js\\src\\xception\\TinyXception.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\\D\\Git\\Temp\\face-api\\node_modules\\face-api.js\\src\\xception\\TinyXception.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/face-api.js/build/es6/xception/extractParams.js

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):

Failed to parse source map from 'D:\\D\\Git\\Temp\\face-api\\node_modules\\face-api.js\\src\\xception\\extractParams.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\\D\\Git\\Temp\\face-api\\node_modules\\face-api.js\\src\\xception\\extractParams.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/face-api.js/build/es6/xception/extractParamsFromWeigthMap.js

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):

Failed to parse source map from 'D:\\D\\Git\\Temp\\face-api\\node_modules\\face-api.js\\src\\xception\\extractParamsFromWeigthMap.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\\D\\Git\\Temp\\face-api\\node_modules\\face-api.js\\src\\xception\\extractParamsFromWeigthMap.ts'

Also I made a build and checked. It was working as required. But I am not sure whether to be used in production or not.
Looking for guidance!
Thanks in advance!

It's even recommended to remove all source map in prod.

The text you posted says "WARNING" and "Module Warning" - they're clearly warnings, not errors. They're only needed for developing when looking at the browser console. You can ignore these warnings.

This is saying that the library providers have not provided source maps for you to debug the code more easily. The application will run but stepping into their code may be a little more difficult since you will be debugging production code, not the original source.
